# Parsing one number into multiple tokens in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR as a parser for my company's latest project. I have been unable to find any information on how to parse one number, say (0005039906179210835699175654) into multiple tokens (a 5 digit number, a 3 digit number, a 14 digit number, and a 6 digit number).

My current code spits back an error,

```
line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '0005039906179210835699175654'
```

Also, on another note, does anyone know how to get the name of a token by using a listener? That's just a bonus question I guess :) Thanks in advance to everyone who responds!

**EDIT:**
To clarify the whole problem, my company receives information in a legacy format from automated systems. This information must be parsed into POJOs for further processing. I am trying to use ANTLR as an easy, smooth, readable, and expandable solution to this. One example is this line:

```
U0005138606179090232769522950 0863832 18322862 0284785                    3
```

Which must be parsed into the sections: U, 00051, 386, 06179090232769, 522950, 0863832, 18322862, 0284785, and 3. Obviously the sections separated by white space are easy to parse but I have been unable to find a way in ANTLR to parse the values not separated by white space. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT2:**
To be perfectly clear as to why I'm using ANTLR instead of just java, my company receives messages in 5 legacy formats, and the system implemented to parse them must be easily expandable to accommodate more in the future. ANTLR is easy to read and understand. Plus, it will be easier to construct additional grammars and listeners than try to maintain a random mess of java.

**EDIT3:**
I thought of a solution but it is pretty janky. My idea is to parse the 28 character number as one token, then split it using java from a listener since it is broken up the same way each time. I'll report back later today on whether I got it to work.

**EDIT4, FINAL UPDATE:**
I have chosen to go my solution mentioned in edit3. It is not pretty, but it works and it is fast enough. Thank your very much to everyone who commented, shared ideas, and stimulated thought!

Comment: Please show us  the entire input.  Surely the real-world problem is not to break this 28 character string into 4 parts?  What else needs to be parsed?

Comment: Could you perhaps do it by having the lexer recognize just the single-character tokens `letter` and `digit` and then do the whole structural definition in the grammar?

Comment: Is the input message always of the same structure?

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error: thanks for the advice, I did give your method a shot but unfortunately it becomes very slow very quickly as file length increases, which is not practical for my project.

Comment: @Raven Unfortunately not, the message is always a series of information on a line, but there are 16 different possible versions for each line depending on the data it contains